# SOLVED: HIBERNATE: Internal Connection Pool limit reached after a few minutes

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, mariadb, database-connection

I have a problem with my Hibernate Connection Pool. After a few minutes of testing, I get an error. I already tried to fix it with the c3p0.jar but it didn't help.
If you have any suggestions please reply to this thread.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/TestProject] threw exception [org.hibernate.HibernateException: The internal connection pool has reached its maximum size and no connection is currently available!] with root cause
org.hibernate.HibernateException: The internal connection pool has reached its maximum size and no connection is currently available!
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.poll(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:322)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.beginTransaction(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:452)
    at dao.AnhangDAO.selectByAufgabeId(AnhangDAO.java:119)
    at org.apache.jsp.Seiten.Aufgaben_jsp._jspService(Aufgaben_jsp.java:400)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1195)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:319)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

**EDIT**: Hibernate Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- JDBC connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/md</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"/>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool, use Hibernate internal connection pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">20</property>

        <!-- Defines the SQL dialect used in Hibernate's application -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory</property>

        <!-- Display and format all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone">CET</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I use the session Object for all my DAO classes, i open them with

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
session.beginTransaction();
```

and after the programm logic i use this code:

```
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.clear();
session.close();
```

**EDIT 2**: My DAO and model classes:

```
package model;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Aufgabe")
public class Aufgabe {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy="increment")
    @Column(name="idAufgabe")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "erstelldatum")
    private LocalDate erstelldatum;

    @Column(name = "titel")
    private String titel;

    @Column(name = "beschreibung")
    private String beschreibung;
    
    @Column(name = "bewertungDoz")
    private int bewertungDoz;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="autor")
    private Benutzer benutzer;
    

    public Aufgabe() {
    }
    
    public Aufgabe(int idAufgabe, LocalDate erstelldatum, String titel, String beschreibung, Benutzer benutzer) {
        super();
        this.id = idAufgabe;
        this.erstelldatum = erstelldatum;
        this.titel = titel;
        this.beschreibung = beschreibung;
        this.benutzer = benutzer;
    }
    
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int idAufgabe) {
        this.id = idAufgabe;
    }

    public LocalDate getErstelldatum() {
        return erstelldatum;
    }

    public void setErstelldatum(LocalDate erstelldatum) {
        this.erstelldatum = erstelldatum;
    }

    public String getTitel() {
        return titel;
    }

    public void setTitel(String titel) {
        this.titel = titel;
    }

    public String getBeschreibung() {
        return beschreibung;
    }

    public void setBeschreibung(String beschreibung) {
        this.beschreibung = beschreibung;
    }

    public int getBewertungDoz() {
        return bewertungDoz;
    }

    public void setBewertungDoz(int bewertungDoz) {
        this.bewertungDoz = bewertungDoz;
    }
    public Benutzer getBenutzer() {
        return benutzer;
    }

    public void setBenutzer(Benutzer benutzer) {
        this.benutzer = benutzer;
    }

    
     @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o){
            if (!(o instanceof Aufgabe)){
                //implicit null check
                return false;
            }
            return this.id==((Aufgabe)o).id;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode(){
            return this.id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Aufgabe [id=" + id + ", erstelldatum=" + erstelldatum + ", titel=" + titel + ", beschreibung="
                    + beschreibung + ", bewertungDoz=" + bewertungDoz + ", benutzer=" + benutzer + "]";
        } 
}
```

and DAO:

```
package dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;

import model.Aufgabe;
import tools.HibernateUtil;

public class AufgabeDAO {


    public List<Aufgabe> selectAll() {
         Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
         session.beginTransaction();

        List<Aufgabe> result = session.createQuery("from Aufgabe order by idAufgabe desc", Aufgabe.class)
                .getResultList();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.clear();
        session.close();
        return result;

    }


    public List<Aufgabe> selectBetween(String startDate, String endDate) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        List<Aufgabe> result = session
                .createQuery("from Aufgabe WHERE erstellDatum >= :anfang AND erstellDatum <= :ende order by id desc",
                        Aufgabe.class)
                .setParameter("anfang", startDate).setParameter("ende", endDate).getResultList();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.clear();
        session.close();

        
        return result;

    }


    public Aufgabe selectWithId(int id) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
         session.beginTransaction();

        Aufgabe selectedA = session.get(Aufgabe.class, id);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.clear();
        session.close();
        return selectedA;
    }



    public List<Aufgabe> selectWithSchwierigkeitsgrad(int schwierigkeitsgrad) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        List<Aufgabe> result = session
                .createQuery("from Aufgabe where bewertungDoz = :bewertungDoz", Aufgabe.class)
                .setParameter("bewertungDoz", schwierigkeitsgrad).getResultList();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.clear();
        session.close();
        
        return result;
    }


    public List<Aufgabe> selectLast12() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        List<Aufgabe> selectedA = session.createQuery("from Aufgabe order by id desc", Aufgabe.class)
                .setMaxResults(12).getResultList();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.clear();
        session.close();

        
        return selectedA;
    }


    public Aufgabe insert(Aufgabe a) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(a);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.clear();
        session.close();
        

        return a;
    }


    public void delete(int id) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Aufgabe aufgabe = session.get(Aufgabe.class, id);
        session.remove(aufgabe);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.clear();
        session.close();

        
    }

    public void update(int id, Aufgabe nAufgabe) {
         Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
         session.beginTransaction();

        session.update(nAufgabe);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.clear();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could show us Hibernate configuration? and the code you're using it in? and how do you use `Session` objects?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri changed it

Comment: `HibernateUtil.java` is the File in which i create the session Factory and make the session out of the Factory. I can send it if you want

Comment: Please add to description this file at AnhangDAO.java,  coming from exception it is the last class in your code that was visited before hibernate internals started to work.

Comment: @DanyloGurianov The error message always shows a different DAO class, but I have now posted the AufgabeDAO.java file

Comment: My guess is , that you might referencing from Benutzer back to Aufgabe  and it introduces cyclic dependency that is not properly hibernate-mapped and calls respective Dao on resolution of each object  , which occupies one connection each time , untill finally you are overspilling your pool limit <property name="connection.pool_size">20</property> and you are getting exception that  you have posted above.

Comment: i don't know why, but it works now. :)

Comment: thx for all your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hibernate 5 or above the GeneratedValue annotation might be creating some problem. Try removing the annotation and assign an ID to the entity from your code.

Find the Entity in your code with @GeneratedValue annotation and remove the annotation.
You have to assign the ID value to the entity after that programatically.

Comment: Yes, im using Hibernate 5.3, can you show alternative code?

Comment: Post your Entities code and also the code you are using to store or update them.

Comment: posted a model and a dao class